# Swap Y Axis in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple `Y-Axis`. One of them is `Primary Y Axis` and rest of the two are `Secondary Y-Axis` as shown in below fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lwks0gt/)

Above code sample renders chart as shown In below image:

[image]

Now dynamically (say on button click event) I want to swap position of two `secondary Y-Axis` so the chart with swapped axis looks like below image:

[image]

If you see in above chart, both `secondary Y-Axis` are swapped.

I don't know how to figure it out. I tried with changing the value of `index` for each Y-Axis as shown below. But that doesn't seems to work.

```
$('#buttonSwap').click(function() {
    console.log(currChart);
  currChart.series[1].yAxis.index = 2;
  currChart.series[2].yAxis.index = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the chart axis for a series by using the [`update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) function like this:

```
currChart.update({series: [{}, {yAxis: '2'}, {yAxis: '1'}]}, true);
```

This will set series 1 to use axis 2, and series 2 to use axis 1.

To change back and forth you could have a toggle like this:

```
var axis = '1';
$('#buttonSwap').click(function() {
  if(axis == '1') {
    currChart.update({series: [{}, {yAxis: '2'}, {yAxis: '1'}]}, true);
    axis = '2';
  } else {
    currChart.update({series: [{}, {yAxis: '1'}, {yAxis: '2'}]}, true);
    axis = '1';
  }
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2Lwks0gt/35/

Comment: +1 Your solution is good. But as a side impact, if I have set some values externally like `extremes` then it will not work. For example: see http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2Lwks0gt/35/  In this fiddle, first click on "set extremes" and then click "Swap axis". It will not work.

Comment: Posted wrong fiddle in previous comment. Here is the correct one:  http://jsfiddle.net/2Lwks0gt/41/

Comment: That is true, I have tried to find a way to mitigate this. The only way I can think of is doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2Lwks0gt/92/